# Using awt classes in model classes

Tags: java, swing, awt

My question is about coding style. Using awt classes like `java.awt.Font` and `java.awt.Color` in a model class is a bad practice? Do I need to create my own duplicates?

Comment: Do you have a particular example in which this question arose?

Comment: I am refactoring a big application and trying to ensure model-view architecture is set. I can not paste any code but actually I decided to use awt classes in model classes already. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using such AWT classes in a model is a reasonable *design* choice. A program that models available font or color choices may very well contain a `ListModel<Font>` or `ListModel<Color>`. The decision is orthogonal to how the corresponding view component [renders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) the list element. Note that a `ListCellRenderer` may interrogate the model to determine the font or color with which to display the element's name.